# actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled gives error in fragment as null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am trying to create swipeable tabs in fragment.So add tab in viewpager.But it gives me error
when actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false) as null pointer exception unable instastaite activity.I am try to resolved issue from past two days but unable do it.Please help me resolved it.please find my Fragment class.

> public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements
>   ActionBar.TabListener{

```
View FaramentView;
private FragmentActivity context;

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    FaramentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, null, false); 

    return FaramentView;

}

@Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    context = (FragmentActivity) activity;


    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Initilization
            viewPager = (ViewPager) FaramentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
             actionBar = context.getActionBar();

            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(context.getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            // Adding Tabs
            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                        .setTabListener(this));
            }

            /**
             * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
             * */
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // on changing the page
                    // make respected tab selected
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                }
            });
}

public LayoutInflater getSystemService(String layoutInflaterService) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Are you using android.app.Activity or android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity?

Comment: using android.app.Activity

Comment: Ah, I just saw your FragmentActivity. If you're using FragmentActivity I believe you need to use getSupportActionBar()

Comment: i am using Fragment can we make tab in fragment

Comment: This sample from Google shows Tabs using fragments: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: but whats is the problem with above code

Comment: replace the line actionBar = context.getActionBar(); with actionBar = context.getSupportActionBar();

Comment: its gives error as is undefined for the type

Comment: Please add the code for your activity to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Android manifest file under activity add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
```

I wanted to add this as a comment, but I couldn't due to the number of reputations.