# How do I remove the Title Bar in a "Fragment Activity"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

That's my code. If I use the "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);", it returns a NullPointerException. Please help! I just want to remove the Title Bar not the Action Bar in my Fragment Activity.

I'm getting the following error:

```html
07-13 04:06:44.623 8610-8610/com.example.swipeviewtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.swipeviewtest, PID: 8610
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.swipeviewtest/com.example.swipeviewtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.example.swipeviewtest.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                             at com.example.swipeviewtest.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
                                                                             at com.example.swipeviewtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you call before `setContentView` ?

Comment: Try getActionBar().setTitle("");

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes, I did!

Comment: @IrisLouis I don't want the Title bar to appear.

Comment: Can you show error at line 34?

Comment: @IrisLouis "actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);" This is line 34.

Comment: @BriefcaseJoe What is activity extends ?

Comment: @IrisLouis it extends "FragmentActivity"

Comment: @BriefcaseJoe try change to ActionBarActivity.

Comment: @IrisLouis That also throws an error! I'm so lost.

Comment: @BriefcaseJoe try fix nullpointer with [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25699910/3832212) or [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019691/nullpointerexception-on-implementation-of-tab-layout) and I think you should search with keyword "NullpointerException setHomeButtonEnabled Actionbar"

Answer (score 1):

Use this way..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: It's returning a "Null Pointer Exception"

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In your Manifest define like that... and it will work

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It returns a "Null Pointer Exception"